# Convert Microsoft product's version (like "Outlook 2003") to build number?

Tags: automation, versioning, semantics

In a [related security.stackexchange.com question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/107470/15648), I asked for ways to find security advisories for specific software. I'd like to automate this process, but I found a mismatch between my database of Microsoft versions that includes build numbers (like 9.00.3027.00) and actual market version names (like - let's say - 2013). How could I translate those in either way (build numbers to version names or the other way round)? Is there a library in any language that would let me do that for Microsoft products (and most preferably other vendors?)

Comment: There's going to be a lot of builds for Outlook 2003, so converting numbers is going to be impossible, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃: you're right, but even having the major number would already be a huge win for me. The thing is that I'm looking for ways to automate the process.

Comment: Maybe that helps? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821549

Comment: @Pekka웃: Yes, but I would have to convert all this knowledge to lot of product-specific functions. I'm looking for libraries that can already do that.